# window.plugins undefined when trying to use the phonegap plugins on android

Tags: android, plugins, cordova

I can't load the plugins in android. I have added the plugin to the plugins.xml list, have added the java code in my project. But still when I call `window.plugins` I get undefined object. Why is this happening? BTW I'm trying to use the share plugin - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share

Just to be clear, I have added the phonegap.js file and the share.js file containing the JS plugin code. Also I have used the EmailComposer plugin for iphone with same code and it works on iphone, i.e. on iphone the window.plugins object it isn't undefined.

Comment: I was using phonegap 1.0.0 not 1.1.0 so the code was correct. The problem was that when I copied the other JavaScript code from the iphone version in xcode, I've copied the phonegap.js file also. So I had the phonegap.js file for iphone and not the phonegap.js file for android. Silly mistake but to be honest I didn't think the two files was different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the exact same issue after noticing... i forgot to reference phonegap-1.1.0.js in my html. I also had to uncomment PhoneGap.addPlugin('share', new Share()); in share.js.

Comment: This was the other part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I think I found the problem with phonegap.
You should go see on this thread, it may explain why you can't access your plugins : [Phonegap background geolocation plugin not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245385/phonegap-background-geolocation-plugin-not-found/31427942#31427942)

Answer (score 0):

In phonegap 1.1.0 we can't call the `windows.plugin` what we need to in your `share.js` instead of

```
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {

});
```

add `navigator.your plugins.js=new WebIntent();` (Java file) and call the plugin as `navigator.your javascript plugin name` in your javascript.

Comment: hai i am using the webintent plugin in android with phonegap 1.0.0.js, but am not using share.js.Am getting the error 'window.plugins.webintent' [undefined] is not an object at the file.Please kindly guide me.Thanks in advance.