# how to send email from android phonegap application?

Tags: jquery, android, email, cordova

I need to get the email composer from the android application using jquery for phonegap and need to send email.Please kindly guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WebIntents](http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins). This solution enables you to send intents from PhoneGap. But please note that this is a Android specific solution.

On iPhones for example you would have to use the [EmailComposer](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir.I have tried the webintent plugin in android.But am getting the error as 'window.plugins.webintent' [undefined] is not an object at the file.And am getting only white screen in the emulator.Please tell me the solution.Thanks in Adavnce.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801434/window-plugins-undefined-when-trying-to-use-the-phonegap-plugins-on-android

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have checked the link above.I am using phonegap 1.0.0.js, but am not using share.js.From where i will get the share.js.Please kindly guide me.Thanks in Advance.