# Email functionality using sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs

Hi friends, I am new to Sencha. I want to do email functionality please help me..
This is my code:

```
Ext.define('NotesApp.view.NoteSettings', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel', 
    xtype: 'formpanel',
    id: 'contactForm',
    url: 'feedback.php',                    
    layout: 'vbox',
    alias: 'widget.notesettingsview',
    config: {
        title: 'Contact',
        iconCls: 'user',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Contact Us',
                instructions: '(email is not required)',

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'name',
                        label: 'Name'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'emailfield',
                        name: 'email',
                        label: 'Email'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textareafield',
                        name: 'message',
                        label: 'Message'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Submit',
                        ui: 'confirm',

                        handler: function(){
                            var values = Ext.getCmp('contactForm').getValues();
                            // prints the values filled in the form 
                            // text fields of name, email and message.     
                            console.log(values.name+","+values.email+","+values.message);                          


                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: 'feedback.php',
                                params : values,
                                success: function(response){
                                    var text = response.responseText;
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', text); 
                                }
                            });     
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846963/how-to-send-email-from-android-phonegap-application

Answer (score 1):

Sencha doesn't provide any "email functionality". Yo need to use some external api to achieve that. 
A made a quick search on the web and I found this:

http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/02/05/introducing-gmailr-an-unofficial-javscript-api-for-gmail/

Maybe you can use it or take it as a basis for your code.

Best regards.

Comment: plesae tell me the way to call java class through button handler

Comment: You will have to read the Cordova (Phonegap) developer docs.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html

Comment: Correct? There is nothing to "correct" in your code, it's fine. I think you mean "write the code i need to send email". And i'm sorry, I'm here to help, no to do someone else's job.

Comment: Hi now i can able to send mail throgh outlook ..but i dont know it wil work when i install in my mobile..u know